# Return Two Related Results Based On Nested SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in a User Table in a SQL Server Database

```
ID    Name    Manager    Employee
_________________________________
1     Greg    17         50
2     Bob     50         54
3     Jim     54         65
```

I'm trying to pull only two records at a time with a single query - here's what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE MANAGER ID = 50 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMPLOYEE = 50)
```

However this pulls only the first record. The desired results are records 1 & 2 (or 2 & 3, 3 & 4, etc.). How can I modify this query to return the correct results?

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: That did it! Such a simple operator I looked over.

Comment: You could also use `OR`, as stated in the answer by @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `OR`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM USERS u
WHERE MANAGER_ID = 50 OR EMPLOYEE = 50;
```

This can also be written as:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM USERS u
WHERE 50 IN (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE);
```